# What does it mean to factor a joint distribution?

Tags: joint-distribution

A book I'm reading (Hogan & Mason, 2012, p37) contains the following passage:

> The joint distribution can be factored in two different ways into
>   conditional and marginal probabilities that reveal different aspects
>   of forecast quality. The calibration-refinement factorization is given by
>   $p\left ( \hat{x},x \right) = p\left (x\mid \hat{x}\right)p\left (\hat{x}\right)$
>   [...]
>   The second way of factoring the joint distribution is known as the likelihood-base rate factorization and is given by
>   $p\left ( \hat{x},x \right) = p\left (\hat{x}\mid x\right)p\left (x\right)$

The context for this passage is the discussion of 2 × 2 contingency tables, where the rows represent binary forecasts and the columns represent binary outcomes. On p32 of the same book a schematic table of this sort is provided.

[image: 2x2 contingency table]

Ideally I'd hope for an answer that doesn't just provide a correct definition, and which also helps to build intuitions about what factorization means and what the point of it is.

Hogan, R. J., & Mason, I. B. (2012). Deterministic forecasts of binary events. Forecast Verification: A Practitioner's Guide in Atmospheric Science, Second Edition, 31-59.

Comment: As far as I know, it is *literally* expressing a probability distribution as a product of factors, i.e. $p=p_1p_2\ldots$. More helpfully, it usually refers to something called graphical models. Wikipedia has some OK examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_graph). (The ones with pictures near the top of the articles. The equations are fine too, but a lot more opaque!)

Comment: If I had to guess it''s saying something about how the joint distribution for two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ can be written as $p(x|y)p(y)$ and also $p(y|x)p(x)$. I have no idea what $X$ and $Y$ are, though

Comment: @GeoMatt Usually it's more than that: the factors need meaningful interpretations as marginal and conditional probabilities or probability densities.

Comment: @whuber yes, I was sloppy. The links I gave explain it better. In areas I run into, the term "factor" would usually not be used for something like Taylor's example, which always holds for any $p(x,y)$. It would normally be associated with conditional independence relationships, I believe?

Comment: @GeoMatt I'm not quite following what "always holds" means.  As the quotation indicates, a factorization of a joint distribution into a marginal and conditional distribution is not unique.  Often this can be done in a great many ways. For example, the standard binormal distribution factors into a Uniform$(0,2\pi)$ distribution and a $\chi^2(2)$ distribution (which in this case are independent).

Comment: @whuber point taken. Below I actually tried to answer the question that was asked :)

Comment: @GeoMatt  Very nicely done! (+1).  Your clear and focused exposition, including appropriate links to terms you use, makes for an admirable answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I am understanding the passage and table correctly, there are essentially two answers: mathematical and qualitative.

Qualitatively, the "different aspects of forecast quality" is essentially the idea of false positives vs. false negatives, or [precision vs. recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall). (I will come back to this.)

Mathematically, the table is comparing two binary variables

$$F =\text{Was an event forecast?}\quad\text{vs.}\quad O =\text{Did an event occur?}$$

and tallying their co-occurences.

The empirical [joint distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution) of these variables would be
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
p(\phantom{\sim}F,O) & p(\phantom{\sim}F,\sim\!O) \\
p(\sim\!F,O) & p(\sim\!F,\sim\!O) \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{n}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where
$$\sim\!F=\text{not }F \quad,\quad \sim\!O=\text{not }O$$
and $n=a+b+c+d$.

The [marginal probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) appear in the margins of the table, and give the total probabilities for forecasts (row sums)
\begin{align}
p(\phantom{\sim}F) &= p(\phantom{\sim}F,O) + p(\phantom{\sim}F,\sim\!O) = \frac{a+b}{n} \\
p(\sim\!F) &= p(\sim\!F,O) + p(\sim\!F,\sim\!O) = \frac{c+d}{n}
\end{align}
and observations (column sums)
\begin{align}
p(\phantom{\sim}O) &= p(F,\phantom{\sim}O) + p(\sim\!F,\phantom{\sim}O) = \frac{a+c}{n} \\
p(\sim\!O) &= p(F,\sim\!O) + p(\sim\!F,\sim\!O) = \frac{b+d}{n} \\
\end{align}

What is not shown in the table are the [conditional probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution). For example what is the probability of an event given that one was forecast? This is given by
$$p(O\mid F)=\frac{p(F,O)}{p(F)}=\frac{a}{a+b}$$
(which could be called the [precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall)). The complement of this would be the fraction of false alarms $p(\sim\!O\mid F)$ (or false positives, more generally).

Another perspective would be to condition on $O$. For example the fraction of events that were forecast is given by
$$p(F\mid O)=\frac{p(F,O)}{p(O)}=\frac{a}{a+c}$$
(which could be called the [recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall)). The complement of this would be the fraction of false negatives $p(\sim\!F\mid O)$.

Mathematically, these perspectives correspond to two different ways of factoring the joint probability
$$p(O\mid F)\,p(F)=p(F,O)=p(F\mid O)\,p(O)$$

(Due to this, a punny personality such as myself might describe the joint probability as the "missing link" in [Bayes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem)!)

Comment: Thanks! Prior to reading your answer I added a few more lines from the original source, since I realised that amount of context I initially provided was perhaps insufficient.

Comment: For intuition I think "forecast" vs. "observed" is better than $\hat{x}$ vs. $x$ (or is it the other way?), so the table is clearer for me :)